# BeautifulSoup object is not extracting html tag from a webpage using 'html.parser'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

My beautifulsoup object not seems working as I passed the 'html.parser' parameter to BeautifulSoup object still it not giving right output as it should be , the output shown by this object is NONE ,its unable to fetch the html tag from webpage passed to it. The complete code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')
print(bs.h1)
```

**Result**:

```
None
```

why this bs object not extracting info inside `h1` tag instead of giving output `None`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me and returns `<h1>An Interesting Title</h1>`.

Comment: I did not get `None`  , check your code again

Comment: Which opersting system you are using I am running this code on python 3.6+ , on os kali linux 2016.2 , I am running this code everytime I am getting same error .

Comment: Your output is correct as I was expecting from mine too bt I alwys get a None